# Can't see elements layout android studio in activity_main.xml

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm beginning with android studio and I can't see the elements (Buttons,TextView,..) I drag and drop in my Design page in `activity_main.xml` page. Those elements are present in my XML file and I can see them when I run my app on my device but I don't know how I can see them on "Design and Blueprint" page.

Thanks for your help.

This is my xml code :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="25dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/message"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/title_home"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/navigation"
        android:layout_width="1dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:menu="@menu/navigation" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="12dp"
        android:layout_height="12dp"
        android:text="ClickMe"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="-73dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="29dp" />

    <android.support.constraint.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guideline"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_begin="20dp" />


</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

And my canvas is totally empty.

EDIT :

I'v got 2 errors :

- Render Problem : `Failed to find style 'bottomNavigationStyle' in current theme   Tip: Try to refresh the layout.`
- Missing Constraints in ConstraintLayout :
  `This view is not constrained. It only has designtime positions, so it will jump to (0,0) at runtime unless you add the constraints`

Comment: Attach a screenshot of your issue.

Comment: I've found this only happens to me if I click the 'add AndroidX' when starting a new project.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can solve this problem by fixing the styles.xml file.

[image: find the styles.xml]

Then you just have to add Base in this code:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
```

The final code:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Base.Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
```

Comment: Thank you! Can you explain why it works when I add Base?

Answer (score 4):

If you have the same error as this page, you should change `com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-alpha3` to `com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-alpha1` in `build.gradle(Module: app)` and and click File -> Invalidate Caches / Restart. Now everything is OK.

[image]

Of course you need internet access to download `com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-alpha1`

Answer (score 1):

to fix this issue:

1. delete API version 27 and 28. tools-->SDK manager uncheck ver 27 and 28
2. uninstall android studio
3. re-install android studio up to version 26 and the problem is solved

Answer (score 1):

[image]

**replace with this inside app gradle**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

1) Try to clean the project by using the option in the build menu in the top

2) Try to invalidate and restart Android Studio by choosing the option in the File menu

3) Try Rebuilding the project by choosing the option in the build menu in the top

Answer (score 0):

I've fixed the problem:

My build.gradle file :

```
dependencies {
 api 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-alpha1'
 api 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0-alpha1'
 api 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.2'
 api 'com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:28.0.0-alpha1'
 application project(':app')
 feature project(':feature')
```

}

I've changed all the lines with "alpha3" by "alpha1".
Thank you @hossein-seifi

Answer (score 0):

Find `Styles.xml` in Values.(res>>Values>>Styles.xml) Change this

Add "Base"

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
to this:

<style name="AppTheme" parent="Base.Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
```

Then clean and build project. Both of those you can do from build menu.

It worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem (Android Studio 4.1.1).  Not only could I not see the elements on the design view, but I couldn't drag any new ones to either the layout or the component tree - nothing happened when I tried to drag and drop them. (They appeared to drag, but they disappeared when I dropped them.)  It was just one activity in one project - others appeared fine.

None of the solutions here worked for me.

Eventually I copied and pasted the code for an existing element, verified it appeared in the component tree, then did a Force Refresh Layout. (I'm sure I'd already tried this last step without success.)

The elements re-appeared and I was able to drag and drop new ones again.

[image: Force Refresh Layout option]